# How upgrading Node.js version may affect project?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have upgraded Node.js version from 10.20.3 to 12.18.3 and now I see `compile error` that `node-sass module not installed`. I did not have this issue on 10.20.3.

My question is more related to how exactly specific Node.js version affects project. Node.js is runtime. Webpack outputs js bundle with dependencies, my own code etc. and then runtime interpreters this bundle. Hence, new version of Node.js may differently interpret code? Like, 10 v. says that `red is blue`, while 12v. says `red is yellow` (just for sake of example).

Also, I had noticed that specific packages require specific Node.js version. It means that this packages may have code that previous Node.js releases don't understand?

Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting your entirev

Comment: @O.Jones Please, re-read my question.